# navigation view with tab layout, go to a tab(fragment) by navigation view item on click

Tags: android-fragments, android-tablayout, navigationview

I have a tabLayout with 4 four tabs(fragments) attached with the support of FragmentPagerAdapter inside the Activity .

I want to navigate to tabs using the navigation view attached. How to go the tabs when I click on the items in the navigation view.

Then how to remove the current four tabs(which is attached with tablayout) with  new fragment.

To Attach Fragments:

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new OfferFragment(), "OFFERS");
    adapter.addFragment(new BookedHistoryFragment(), "Booked History");
    adapter.addFragment(new ReviewFragment(), "Reviews");
    adapter.addFragment(new AvailableRoomFragment(), "Available");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Sub classAdapter to add the fragments.

```
class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

Navigation View actions:

```
mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_offers) {
                int tabCount= tabLayout.getTabCount();
                // I want to move to other tab.

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"First",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Booking.class);
//                    startActivity(intent);
            }
            else if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_avail_room) {
                 // Then I want to remove Four tabs and call a new fragment.
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Second",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return false;
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tell the tab index while clicking the item in navigation view. The code is below.

For the second problem, I started the new activity and attached fragments in that.

```
mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_offers) {
            TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(2);
            tab.select();
        }
        else if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_avail_room) {
             // Here I started a new activity and attached fragment.
        }
        return false;
    }

});
```